# Variables not showing in MATLAB workspace

Tags: matlab, variables, workspace

Every now and then, variables just stop showing up in the Workspace pane. `who` and `whos` show that there are definitely variables in the workspace - I just can't see them in the Workspace pane. Only restarting MATLAB resolves this. Why is this happening?

Comment: I would file this as a possible bug to MathWorks. Specify your platform, and if possible how to reproduce this behavior... Personally, this never occurred to me

Comment: right click the workspace and hit refresh.. do they appear?

Comment: What version of MATLAB are you running and what platform are you on? Do you have any reproduction steps which will duplicate this behavior?

Comment: Have you tried scrolling down?

Comment: Are you using a recent release on OSX? In that case, please, please report this as a bug to MathWorks. They need to know about these interface bugs so that they get fixed.

Comment: I'm using 2010a on OSX 10.6.  I've already tried refreshing, and there's nowhere to scroll--there's nothing in the Workspace pane, so how would it overflow?  This has happened several times.  One thing that consistently reproduces this behaviour is by fetching a large amount of data from a database into a variable, but this is not the only time I've seen this happen.

Comment: @GarlicFries: It may help to increase the Java Heap Memory on your system.

Comment: @Jonas, already tried that.  No love...

Comment: @GarlicFries Has this been resolved? This happened for me a few times on OSX, I started using pack in a somewhat paranoid manner and it never happened again -- though I am not sure if it actually helped.

Comment: I'm not aware of a fix other than upgrading to 2011--fixed things for me.

Comment: I encountered this whilst switching, at a breakpoint, to my base workspace. Obviously 999 times out of 1000 the workspace viewer updates with the switch, but this this I got lucky. Perhaps OP did the same?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I filed a bug report and never heard a word...  I upgraded to 2011a, and haven't had this problem since.  Because of this, because no one provided an answer and because I can no longer investigate others' further suggestions, I am accepting this as my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Do you invoke the Debugger and return to the workspace afterwards without closing it?
Notice the changed command promt, as it starts with **K>>** now. The invocation causes a context switch and your variables dissapear (until you stop the debugger)...

But that's just a guess. I was confused about this a couple of times myself during my starting time with MATLAB.